# D3.js sunburst sorting by size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to sort my sunburst graph by the sizes of the arcs. Here is the code that I am using

```
    browsable(tagList(
  html_dependency_vue(),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/d3"),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/d2b@0.5.1/build/d2b.js"),
  tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/vue-d2b"),
  tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"),
  tags$script(src = 'https://d3js.org/d3-hierarchy.v1.min.js'),
  tags$div(
    id = "app",
    style = "height:400px",
    tag(
      "sunburst-chart",
      list(":data" = "sunburstChartData", ":config" = "sunburstChartConfig")
    )),
  tags$script(HTML(
    sprintf(
"
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
  'sunburst-chart': vued2b.ChartSunburst
},
  data: {
    sunburstChartData: %s,
    sunburstChartConfig: function(chart) {
      var d3_category30 = [
  '#1f77b4', '#aec7e8',
  '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78',
  '#2ca02c', '#98df8a',
  '#d62728', '#ff9896',
  '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5',
  '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2',
  '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7',
  '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d',
  '#17becf', '#9edae5',
  'salmon','lightsalmon',
  'lightsteelblue','steelblue',
  'yellow','orange',
  '#cccccc','#dddddd','#eee','#aaa',
  '#123456','black'];
d3.scale.category30 = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3_category30);
};
      var color = d3.scale.category30();
      chart.label(function(d){return d.name});
     // chart.sunburst().size(function(d){return d.size});
     chart.color(function(d){return color(d.name);})
     var namesize = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
                    .rollup(function(a){return a.length;})
                    .entries(data)
                    .sort(function(a, b){ return d3.ascending(a.values, b.values); });


    //chart.color(function(d){return typeof(d.color) === 'undefined' ? '#BBB' : d.color; })
      }
  },
})
",
      hier_json1
    )
  ))
))
```

I have also tried the following code among other variations of it.

```
var root = d3.hierarchy(root)
.sum(function (d) { return d.size; })
.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });
```

but I neither one has worked for me. The hierarchy has been generated in R using d3_nest. All of the code that is posted is in R, code that is in-between '' is javascript. I am inexperienced with javascript.Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Okay, so I went through the source code here : https://unpkg.com/d2b@0.5.1/build/d2b.js and found the code responsible for the sorting

```
 base(sunburst, $$).addProp('pie', d3.pie().sort(null)).addProp('ancestorBanding', d3.scaleLinear()).addProp('descendantBanding', d3.scalePow().exponent(0.85))
// Datum Level Accessors
.addPropFunctor('duration', 250).addPropFunctor('innerRadius', 30).addPropFunctor('outerRadius', 200).addPropFunctor('ancestorPadding', 10).addPropFunctor('ancestorRatio', 0.2).addPropFunctor('descendantLevels', Infinity).addPropFunctor('startAngle', 0).addPropFunctor('endAngle', 2 * Math.PI).addPropFunctor('showLabels', false).addPropFunctor('zoomable', true).addPropFunctor('highlight', true)
// Node Level Accessors
.addPropFunctor('key', function (d) {
  return $$.label(d);
}).addPropFunctor('label', function (d) {
  return d.label;
}).addPropFunctor('color', function (d) {
  return color($$.label(d));
}).addPropFunctor('children', function (d) {
  return d.children;
}).addPropFunctor('size', function (d) {
  return d.size;
});
```

I have been trying to change the `.sort(null) to .sort(function(a,b){return b.value - a.value})`
Unfortunately, I haven't been successful in doing so. Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that the sorting function is actually sorting real values?  I don't know what your dataset is, but if there isn't a property called value or values, I don't think sort will actually sort anything.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. It is true, that my data set does not have anything called value or values. My valuecols is called size. But even if I replace .value with .size I still don't get anything.

Comment: Well sometimes the data gets transformed. It may be something like a.data.size that you need to use.  Try to use a console.log and verify that there are truly values there.

Comment: I am not sure how to do a console.log, I am running this in R. Would that information be in the nested JSON?

Comment: In the sort function, do console.log('size: ' + a.size), if that makes sense.

Comment: Like this:  var root = d3.hierarchy(root)
.sum(function (d) { return d.size; })
.sort(function(a, b) { return b.data.size - a.data.size; } console.log('size: ' + a.size));               I still don't get any output.

Comment: More like .sort(function (a,b){console.log('size' + a.size);  return b.size - a.size;}).  The console.log is only there to see what values are in the variable a.  If nothing shows then you change it up until you see one

Comment: So I still get no output. Should the console.log output a log of what the variable is called? Do you mean I keep adding different variables like console.log('size' + a.size + a.data.size)? is there a list of possible transformations somewhere?

Comment: yea that or actually if you just do console.log(a), that may work

Comment: I tried this but still nothing,    var root = d3.hierarchy(root) 
       .sum(function (d) { return d.size; }) 
       .sort(function (a,b){console.log(a); return b.size - a.size;});        Is there a list of what it may have been transformed to somewhere?

Comment: Okay there is an easier way.  If you are viewing this on a browser, instead of using console.log(), just type in debugger;. It will stop the code there and you can examine the objects in the browser

Comment: I am running all of the code in R studio. I have never used javascript in a browser before.

Comment: Ah I see.  Im not 100% familiar with how R Studio operates.  There is another thing you can try though.in the code that you originally posted.  Did you replace values with size?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work either. However, I didn't keep both code that I was hoping would sort the arcs. I either did var root = ... or I did var name size = ... neither code worked even when I replaced value(s) with size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else who will one day have this same issue. If you are using vue.d2b to create your sunburst graphs, the way to sort the graph is with the following code.

```
 chart.sunburst().pie().sort(function(a,b){return d3.descending(a.value, b.value)});
```